# Slickgrid Horizontal Scrollbar Covers Last Row

Tags: slickgrid

When a Slickgrid is contained in a *div* with fixed width and a horizontal scrollbar becomes necessary, that scrollbar covers the last row of data.

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/LtsvJ/

How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/6d3b8a0844a0ef8528b11e67ef0bd0f5265d1c7b.