# Slickgrid Horizontal Scrollbar adds Random Whitespace in IE9

Tags: slickgrid

While testing the fix for this issue:

[Slickgrid Horizontal Scrollbar Covers Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11806720/141172)

I noticed that the updated code causes "random" whitespace below the horizontal scrollbar in IE9.  The jsFiddle does not run in IE9 with Browser Mode set to IE7 (*SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number*)

The error is *not seen* in:

- Chrome (current)
- Safari (current)
- Firefox (current)
- IE 9 with Browser Mode IE8

Fiddle demonstrating problem (view in **IE9**):

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/LtsvJ/9/

Added a comment to the [appropriate ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/414) but lack permission to re-open it.

*NOTE: slick.grid.js is hosted on my own server because IE9 complained that 
https://raw.github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/master/slick.grid.js 
reported an incorrect MIME type and refused to load it.  That code corresponds to the change 
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/6d3b8a0844a0ef8528b11e67ef0bd0f5265d1c7b*

**UPDATE**

**IE9 in IE7 Browser Mode**

There is a JavaScript error in IE9's IE7 Browser Mode that prevents the grid from rendering at all.  However, the call stack is empty in the IE9 console.  The error is

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number  
show, line 90 character 1
```

Clicking on the link in the JS Console gives the error *Source code is not available for this location*.

**IE9 Regular Mode**

Added screenshots from IE9.  Note that there is no JavaScript error reported in IE9.

[image]

Comment: Don't have access to IE9 right now.  Could you add a screenshot and a details exception stacktrace?

Comment: Added screenshot and clarified that the JavaScript error only happens in IE7 Document Mode.  The error with the extra whitespace happens in IE9's native mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens only when you host your own slick.grid.js.  After I changed your jsfiddle to include http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js (not http://raw.github..., which doesn't have the right MIME type), everything started working.

IE7 mode still fails, but the error seems to come from jsfiddle.net and not from SlickGrid.

Comment: I'm not seeing this anymore in the current version.